# onOptionsItemSelected not working with my menu

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a toolbar in my `MainActivity.kt` which has assigned the `app:menu="@menu/top_menu`:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

        android:gravity="center_vertical">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:title="@string/app_name"
            app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
            app:menu="@menu/top_menu"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

And this **top_menu** that I have assigned to has this code:

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemSettings"
        android:title="@string/title_activity_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

**The problem is**, I can't access the **Menu Item** using the code:

```
 override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId){
            R.id.itemSettings -> Toast.makeText(this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        return true
    }
```

What do I need to do to assign this code to the menu that I have?

Comment: Post the code from onCreate() that sets the toolbar as actionbar.

Comment: @forpas ```toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need **inflate** your menu:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.top_menu, menu)
  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}
```